# java based configuration for web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml

Since last eight years I am working with spring. Recently I encountered a scenario where I could not able to use spring or it's related component and application should be purely based on Java EE 7. 
So I need to know is there any possible way to skip WEB.xml and have related settings like resource-ref and security-constraint inside some Java configuration file ? is possible to have these settings with the help of ServletContainerInitializer ?

I need to deploy this application in Tomcat 8.x

Comment: why you don't want to use the `web.xml` ? It's the easiest solution

Comment: I have a conception that web.xml would be obsolete in future releases of J2EE, also I would like to have my code base xml free.

Comment: The web.xml will never be obsolete :) Yeah, it;s indeed XML, but it has a lot of advantages. For instance it;s a single point where you can look up a filter, context listener, servlet etc, while if you use annotations you should search through the whole codebase. Also you can do modifications to your config without having to rebuild your application, which IMHO is a huge advantage

Answer (score 0):

Alright... just gone through JSR 250 and there are couple of annotations to solve my problem :) Resource, DeclareRoles, RolesAllowed, PermitAll

e.g.

```
@Resource(name="myDataSource", lookup="java:comp/DefaultDataSource")
DataSource myDS;
```